# JSON - Convert code from JQuery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i'm trying to convert a code from JQuery to PHP to do a json POST request to remote server.

My Jquery code is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://http://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track",
                data: { 
                    action: "trackpackages", 
                    format: "json", 
                    locale: "it_IT", 
                    version: "1", 
                    data: '{"TrackPackagesRequest":{"appType":"WTRK","uniqueKey":"","processingParameters":{},"trackingInfoList":[{"trackNumberInfo":{"trackingNumber":"780909642310","trackingQualifier":"","trackingCarrier":""}}]}}'
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                console.log( msg );
            });
        }
    )
});
```

I would like to do same POST request call from PHP, but i can not.

My PHP code is:

```
$data = array("action" => "trackpackages", "data" => array ('TrackPackagesRequest' => array('appType' => 'WTRK', 'uniqueKey' => '', 'processingParameters' => '{}', 'trackingInfoList' => array(array('trackNumberInfo' => array('trackingNumber' => '780909642310', 'trackingQualifier' => '', 'trackingCarrier' => ''))))), 'format' => 'json', 'locale' => 'it_IT', 'version' => '1');


$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Remote server is not responding properly and seems not receive the data properly encoded. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank You!

Comment: In your jQuery code the `data` parameter inside `data` is just a string (looks like JSON), whereas in your PHP code it is an object. Maybe try to adjust that.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have tried your suggest, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

    /* You need to define that parameter separately,
     * as it is supposed to be passed as a JSON String.
     */
    $data_field = array(
        'TrackPackagesRequest' => array(
            'appType' => 'WTRK',
            'uniqueKey' => '',
            'processingParameters' => (Object)array(), // Will be stringified as {}
            'trackingInfoList' => array(
                array(
                    'trackNumberInfo' => array(
                        'trackingNumber' => '780909642310',
                        'trackingQualifier' => '',
                        'trackingCarrier' => ''
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $data = array(
        "action" => "trackpackages",
        'format' => 'json',
        'locale' => 'it_IT',
        'version' => '1',
        "data" => json_encode($data_field) // Insert the String
    );

    $ch = curl_init('http://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // http_build_query will convert your parameters to param1=val1&param2=val2...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;

?>
```